# Does it invalidate wudu?

Tags: women, wudu, sajda, ruku

when the air is trapped in front passage of women. I think many women faces this and after movement in prayer like in ruku or sujud the air bubbles escapes or it feels likes bubbles. does it invalidate wudu ?